# Jquery date picker (select multipe hours on a particular day)

Tags: jquery

I have looked up at several jquery date picker.I need a date picker that allows the user to select multiple time on a day (after every half an hour). The user is picking room reservations, multiple hours on a particular day (similar to google calendar). Therefore, I want the date picker to show such explicitly.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement fullcalendar - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ would provide the ideal solution.